# Problema com função Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

A função que eu criei em Jquery, não está sendo chamada no 1º click, só é acionada no 2º.
Estou usando asp.net, C#, preciso que o componente panel inicie oculto, com isso, ao clicar na tag p ele aparecer e assim chamar o metodo toggle() toda vez que clicar nela.
Meu código é este:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#pnlSalas").css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('.a').click(function () {
            $("#pnlSalas").toggle();
            $("#pnlSalas").css('visibility', 'visible');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Tentou usar o metodo on() ?

Comment: Tentei e dá na mesma .. :(

Comment: @renan estou usando painel do asp.net, coloquei só pra saberem com o que estou mexendo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que quando usas

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pnlSalas").css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

aos olhos do jQuery esse elemento não está escondido.

Aí quando fazes `.toggle()` no primeiro click ele esconde, ou seja fica com `style="visibility: visible; display: none;"`. Portanto ele esconde apesar de não estar visivel ao utilizador desde inicio.

Na prática podes simplificar para isto:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pnlSalas").toggle();
    $('.a').click(function () {
        $("#pnlSalas").toggle();
    });
});
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/hrLL6dmL/

Comment: funcionou, obrigado.

Comment: @AndreeH se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite.Reparei que tens muitas perguntas que não estão aceites.

Comment: eu consegui com este trecho de código mesmo 
`$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pnlSalas").toggle();
    $('.a').click(function () {
        $("#pnlSalas").toggle();
    });
});`

Comment: @AndreeH http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/129